# MDX Filter with ALL option

Tags: ssas, mdx

I currently have an MDX filter with the following formula:

```
Descendants([Start_Date].[Start Year],, SELF_AND_AFTER)
```

And I see All, 2012,2011,2010 which is what I expect.

However, the All sums everything. What I want is to just see all the years and not the total sum for all. So if I select All, it will show me 2010, 2011, and 2012 separately and that's it, not a fourth value summing all the years together.

Anyway to achieve this?

Comment: What is the whole MDX request ?

Answer (score 1):

What you're looking for is achieved using [VisualTotals](http://www.iccube.com/support/documentation/mdx/VisualTotals.html) in MDX

```
 VisualTotals( Descendants( ... ) )
```

If this does not fit into your query you can create a 'new' [ALL] member that is the sum of the years. Something like

```
 MEMBER [Start_Date].[Start Year].[All].[New All] as  Sum( Descendants([Start_Date].[Start Year],, SELF_AND_AFTER) - [All], [Measures].currentmember)
```